# Which namespace/DLL to use for ValueConversion in SL4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am converting a SL3 application to SL4 and facing some issues.

Can anyone provide me the namespace or DLL name for ValueConversion.

I am getting error on the following statement.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(ToolType), typeof(bool))]
```

Thanks for sharing your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is not part of Silverlight Runtime Classes now.
it was there in System.Windows.Data namespace before.
Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.valueconversionattribute.aspx

you can use IValueConverter interface as before.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following implementation in ClipFlair Studio:
http://ClipFlair.codeplex.com (see Client/Helpers/WPF_Compatibility/WPF_Compatibility.Silverlight project at the sourcecode)