# Localizing windows phone 8 app - XAML ListView dynamic binding to Resources.resx keys

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

For a windows phone 8 app, I have used Resource.resx to display local language translation of a random text for a single `TextBlock` with no issues.

Now I would like to do similar thing with about 100 category names stored in a table.

I would like to bind the table to a `ListView`.

Should I use each one of the 100 category names as keys in the Resource.resx files? Or should I name the keys like `Category_1001` instead of for e.g. `Breads`, so that if I ever need to change `Breads` to `Bread`, I don't have to change whole lot of code?

**Question**: If I'm going the second route (`Category_1001`), is there any way to do this declaratively in XAML or do I need to do this programmatically in xaml.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are so many objects of the same type, I can suggest the following solution.

In *.resx file you can store `Category_XXXX` keys. After that, you can create a **enum**

```
public enum Category
{
    Bread = 1, // number here should correspond to the proper resource key
    Oil = 2,
    Potato = 3,
    Tomato = 4,
    ...
}
```

And then create your value converter

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Category), typeof(String))]
public class CategoryConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int category = (int)value;
        string res;
        try
        {
            res = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(string.Format("Category_{0:d4}", (int)category));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           res = string.Format("Unable to obtain resource {0}: {1}", Category, e.Message);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
         throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And then in your *.xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Category, Converter={StaticResource MyCategoryConverter}}" />
```

You also can extract the method in order to use it in your ViewModels.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm trying to follow the post and found that 1)`ValueConversion` attribute was not required (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8693338/1541224), 2) apparently `Convert`'s signature has changed from `CultureInfo culture` to `string language` and **3) You have `CategoryConverter` class but `StaticResource MyCategoryConverter`  - is there anything missing?** my xaml is unable to resolve `CategoryConverter` - but code behind can.

Comment: I see now I had to add create the static resource in xaml page's resources http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Good to hear that you have understood it by yourself!